# Why RecordType is added in the SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, soql

Why is `RecordType` added in the below SOQL Query?

`[Select UserId, LoginTime from LoginHistory RecordType where UserId=:UserInfo.getUserId()];`

Here `LoginHistory` is an Object. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

RecordType is the alias for the object LoginHistory.